# Getting this error message while running Load Test in Azure "Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore"

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, keystore

I have uploaded .jmx script and CVS files in the test plan. And added an "Authorize Token" as parameter in the Environment Variables (as I don't want to give secrets). So when the test is executed,  "Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore" message is displayed in the log file and test is failed. How do I fix this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your test is using [client-side certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) you need to:

1. Upload the [keystore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_KeyStore) along with your test plan and the CSV file
2. Set the corresponding [JMeter system properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter):

   - `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` - with the path to the keystore file
   - `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` - with the password for the keystore file

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I created keystore file, uploaded in test plan and updated system properties too. Still I get the same error. Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore